# Swift Random Color Generator

Tags: swift, random, uibutton, uilabel, generator

Is it possible to change the color a button with a label using a random generator?

For ex.. Label "A" is the title/color dictator and will notify "Button 1 and Button 2" what colors they will generate to be randomly.

Comment: A color is made up of 3 components: red, green and blue. Just generate 3 random numbers between 0 and 1 and make a `UIColor` from them

Answer (score 1):

```
let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
let myColor =  UIColor(red: randomRed/255, green: randomGreen/255, blue: randomBlue/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: could I use more than just 3 colors ?

Comment: This will generate a random color. It won't necessarily be red, green or blue if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Please see my edit, this is actually a better solution for your case

Comment: Ok. Thank you @JP Aquino

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**Answer 1:** Generate random colour from array(restrict to 3 colour)

**Note:** you have to set initial backgroundColor to your button in viewDidLoad

```
   yourButtonName.backgroundColor = .red // set any colour

   //Button background array
   let buttonBG = [UIColor.red,UIColor.green,UIColor.black]

   //Button title colour array
   let buttonTitle = [UIColor.orange,UIColor.cyan,UIColor.yellow]
```

**Usage:** Try below code inside your button action.It will generate randomColor assigned from array...

```
    let BGRandomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonTitle.count)))
    yourButtonName.tintColor = buttonTitle[BGRandomIndex]

    let TitleRandomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonBG.count)))
    yourButtonName.backgroundColor = buttonBG[TitleRandomIndex]
```

**Answer 2:** Generate Random Colour.

```
func randomCGFloat() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
}

func randomColor() -> UIColor {
    let r = randomCGFloat()
    let g = randomCGFloat()
    let b = randomCGFloat()

    // If you wanted a random alpha, just create another
    // random number for that too.
    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
}
```

**Usage:** Try below code inside your button action.It will generate randomColor on every button click...

```
 yourButtonName.backgroundColor = randomColor() // to get random background button backgroundColor

 yourButtonName.tintColor = randomColor() //to get random background button title color
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{

    let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)

    }
```

You're going to need a function to produce random CGFloats in the range 0 to 1:

you can use

```
CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
```

alternate for drand48()

If you want a alpha as a random, just create another random number for that
Just create a random background for your view like

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor().getRandomColor()
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer